# Getting apt-get errors after unsuccessful Oracle Java instalation

Tags: apt, java, jdk

I started getting errors when installing packages using `apt-get` after unsuccessful Oracle JDK 7 installation.These errors come up even when I'm installing packages unrelated to Java. For some reason apt-get tries to install jdk (and fails) every time I install something. Here is the output from when I try to install vim: How can I fix this?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1 036 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2 458 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 [1 036 kB]
Fetched 1 036 kB in 0s (1 778 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package vim.
(Reading database ... 266223 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../vim_2%3a7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vim (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2017-12-09 21:57:26--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 81.198.165.219, 81.198.165.233
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|81.198.165.219|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-12-09 21:57:26--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 184.86.54.138, 2a02:26f0:18:489::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:18:499::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|184.86.54.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1512849566_e3b01a3ab3696363f4f5cbd105ec04d6 [following]
--2017-12-09 21:57:26--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1512849566_e3b01a3ab3696363f4f5cbd105ec04d6
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|81.198.165.219|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-12-09 21:57:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up vim (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vim (vim) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vimdiff (vimdiff) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rvim (rvim) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rview (rview) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vi (vi) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/view (view) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/ex (ex) in auto mode
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer` ? or `sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer`